# Can't setup favicon Angular 6 app

Tags: javascript, angular, favicon, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and can't setup favicon for my app. It is absent at all.   Here is my `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../wwwroot/dist",
            "deployUrl": "/dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "frontend",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

In `index.html` i have `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`.

`favicon.ico` located in `src/favicon.ico`.

I have already tried to clear cash and restart app multiple times as people advised in similar questions, but it didn't help. 
Also tried to add dummy param to favicon in index.html like `href="favicon.ico?any=param"`

What should i do for make it works? Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error here? Does it find an image or do you get a 404 for the favicon.ico? You can try to do a 'ng build' and check the 'dist' folder. When the correct favicon.ico was copied in the folder, it was a probably a caching issue.

Comment: I didn't get any error. Favicon in the vrowser is just empty

Comment: in your `angular.json`, try using `favicon.ico` instead of `src/favicon.ico`. That's how my app is set up and the favicon is in the src/ directory.

Comment: @rhavelka if i do so - i will get an error `The favicon.ico asset path must start with the project source root.`

Comment: Ok, I have my `"root": "src"` which explains that error and why I don't have src prefixing any of my files. But it doesn't explain why your favicon isn't working... I assume that you have a favicon.ico, and it isn't anything like favicon.png. Does anything show up on your tab like the default favicon?

Comment: just saw your comment about it being empty. I would say try setting the favicon back to the angular default, and trying to work your way from there. It seems like you are doing everything right.

Comment: Have you tried to build the app and looked into the 'dist' folder? Would be helpful for error resolution.

Answer (score 12):

The public folder for images and static stuff is /assets. Put the icon-image in there.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/icon.png">
```

Comment: This worked for me, but also restarting `ng serve` also allowed me to keep the .ico file in the /src directory.

Answer (score 8):

Put your `favicon.png` in your asset folder and change the path in `index.html` like so:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/favicon.png">
```